# Virtual Assistant Bot Framework Alexa channel HTTP status code GatewayTimeout

Tags: botframework, bots

I have a QnA bot and I configured Alexa channel based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-alexa?view=azure-bot-service-4.0.
From Alexa developer console, I was able to trigger my greeting message (from DefaultActivityHandler.cs). But received "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout" after the initial greeting.
My QnA bot works fine on other channels (direct line and web chat).

Thank you!

Comment: am also trying something in alexa with bot framework VA template, please let me know if you have found any way.